# How to collapse SearchView on backpressed using appcompat v7.?

Tags: android, searchview, android-appcompat

I am using `appcompat v7` for searchview with toolbar except actionbar. below is my menu xml file and java file.

menu file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sort"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_sort"
        android:title="@string/sort"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

java file:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);

         MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);


        if (searchItem != null) {
            searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        }
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(MainActivity.this.getComponentName()));
        }
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

now i want to collapse searchview if it is expanded otherwise want to work backpressed on `backpressed()` method. how can i achieve this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collapsing on backpressed is handled by default in my own setup. I didn't implement a custom onBackPressed method. I did nothing special except extending from ActionBarActivity.

I used MenuItemCompat to get actionview, that might do the trick.

### This is my menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.yourapp.youractivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/nav_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

### This is how i create the menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.shop_list, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = 
                  (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    //Using MenuItemCompat here, that can do the trick
    searchView = 
            (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.
                        getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.search));

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    //etc...
    //etc...

    return true;
}
```

Comment: using  app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" it solved.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the Class and extend `ActionBarActivity` in your Class 
(Example: - public class Home extends `ActionBarActivity`)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

For collapsing the SearchView: Try this,

```
menu.collapseActionView();
```

(or)

```
searchView = menuItem.getActionView().
```

(or)

```
searchView.onActionViewCollapsed()
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onBackPressed` call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` or store SearchView as `Activity` field and call `searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();` but that can require additional work when restoring your `Toolbar` state (title state etc.).

Comment: but how can i know that searchview is expanded or not.? so that i can collapse it.

Comment: searchView.isIconified(), returns true when collapsed. Also I suggest check google.io app approach for searching (it's open source).